# Minimum number of config servers needed for Mongo Cluster

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing, sharding

I am trying to test sharding in MongoDB cluster.

I am folllowing  [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) .

They suggest to use 3 config servers. Can I set up a cluster with 1 or 2 servers? Or I need 3 or more config servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MongoDB docs:
The config server processes are mongod instances that store the cluster’s metadata. You designate a mongod as a config server using the --configsvr option. Each config server stores a `complete copy` of the cluster’s metadata.

Hence for test setup 1 config server should be fine , but for production it is recommended to use replicated 3 config servers.